# Query to join tables where id matches and row exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm in need of a MySQL query that join several tables only if those tables have a matching ID and it actually exists in the table.

I have 1 parent table and several sub tables. The parent tables contains every row while the sub tables only contain the rows that they need. I need to join the parent table with the sub tables if the parent table has an ID that exists in one of the sub tables.

This is what I am currently using which does not work. This query ends up having no result because the sub table rows may not exist. For example, 1 row may exist in the "widgets" table and the "widget_login" table because the widget is a "login" widget, but all the other tables are empty. But it should still check all tables. I'm not sure how to overcome this.

```
SELECT FROM widgets
JOIN widget_login ON widget_login.id=widgets.id
JOIN widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id
JOIN widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id
WHERE widgets.type='specific_type'
etc...
```

Comment: This will work fine if you need only the matching rows that exist in all your child table otherwise use LEFT OUTER JOIN if you need to display every row in your parent table even if they exist or not in your child table

Comment: Is there anyway to leave out rows from the child tables that don't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes. And add columns to select, e.g. *.

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
INNER JOIN widget_login ON widget_login.id=widgets.id
INNER JOIN widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id
INNER JOIN widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id
WHERE ... etc etc
```

EDIT: If you only want to select from widgets, then use EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
WHERE EXISTS (select * from widget_login where widget_login.id=widgets.id)
AND EXISTS (select * from widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id)
AND EXISTS (select * from widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id)
WHERE ... etc etc
```

or IN:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
WHERE id IN (select id from widget_login)
AND id IN (select id from widget_admin)
AND id IN (select id from widget_facebook)
WHERE ... etc etc
```

BTW: It seems strange that the IDs of the various tables shall equal. A column named ID in a table widgets should identify a widget record, wheras a column named ID in a table widget_login should identify a login record. Check this; maybe you are confusing IDs.

EDIT: One more remark: If you are looking for widgets that exist in at least one of the three tables use EXISTS or IN with OR instead of AND.

EDIT: To join all tables and make sure that the widget exists in at least one of the tables use outer join and check your results for nulls:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
LEFT JOIN widget_login ON widget_login.id=widgets.id
LEFT JOIN widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id
LEFT JOIN widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id
WHERE (widget_login.id IS NOT NULL OR widget_admin.id IS NOT NULL OR widget_facebook.id IS NOT NULL)
AND ... etc etc
```

Be aware with further criteria that the columns of the other tables can be null for a record. E.g. to add AND widget_admin.name <> 'BAD' would remove all outer joined records, because NULL is not <> 'BAD'.

Comment: It would need to include the data from the child tables. I don't know if the second or third query you mentioned would do that. The first query comes up with no result, i'm not sure why. The only time anything shows as a result is when I use left join, however the result from that isn't 100% what I want. I mentioned those issues in my other comments. I appreciate your response.

Comment: So I guess you want to join the tables but assure that there is an entry in at least one of them? I've edited my answer accordingly. If this is still not what you want, then describe in more detail, please.

Comment: An image is better than words. Take a look: http://i.imgur.com/py65WyJ.png. This is only a part of the array, but you get the point. Many columns have null data because its pulling info from the child table that doesn't exist. For example, the columns pertaining to "admin" are null. Also, one of the major issues is it removes the data from [id]. Its null even though id is never null in the table. I have no idea why its removing that. To note, i've tried adding the WHERE clause in your last example, i've also tried using LEFT OUTER JOIN. Both don't seem to make any difference.

Comment: In a perfect world, id would actually include the id and columns such as "admin" wouldn't be in that image because there is no "admin" widget created. There is only a login widget created.

Comment: I am sorry to say, I don't understand the image and it seems I have not the slightest idea what you are actually after. A select statement retrieves rows and columns. So why not edit your request, show us some table content, say three widgets and some entries in the other tables and then show the desired result lines?

Answer (score 1):

Replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN. It get all rows from widgets and related rows (if exist) from joined tables

```
SELECT FROM widgets
LEFT JOIN widget_login ON widget_login.id=widgets.id
LEFT JOIN widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id
LEFT JOIN widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id
WHERE ... etc etc
```

Comment: The issues I have with this query is that it includes the empty rows from the tables that don't have the id and it removes the id from the array that I get from the query, so I can't use the id on the page. Is there anyway to avoid either of those issues?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you illusrate with the tables' data and desired result of the query?

Comment: Using the query above, the output array removes the id from the parent table. So it may looks like: [id]=>, [data2]=>"bla", [data3]=>"bla", etc.., etc... It also includes rows that don't exist from the child tables. So for example, widget_admin contains no rows, however the result includes a row with all columns empty. It does this with all child tables that I join.

Comment: LEFT [OUTER] JOIN includes all fields from left table (widgets in your case) and matching filds from right table (e.g. widget_admin). If there is no matching row nulls are related. Simple JOIN leaves only matching rows but if you use 2 inner joins with widget_admin and widget_login there is no the same row in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively equal to the INNER JOIN . But will show records only if the id exist in all your child tables. You can modify the `WHERE` condition to filter out the rows

```
  SELECT FROM widgets
    LEFT OUTER JOIN widget_login ON widget_login.id=widgets.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN widget_admin ON widget_admin.id=widgets.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN widget_facebook ON widget_facebook.id=widgets.id
    WHERE widget_login.id IS NOT NULL 
          AND  widget_admin.id IS NOT NULL 
          AND  widget_facebook.id IS NOT NULL
```